# How do the Perl 6 set operations compare elements?

Tags: set, raku, moarvm

*Running under moar (2016.10)*

Consider this code that constructs a set and tests for membership:

```perl6
my $num_set = set( < 1 2 3 4 > );
say "set: ", $num_set.perl;
say "4 is in set: ", 4 ∈ $num_set;
say "IntStr 4 is in set: ", IntStr.new(4, "Four") ∈ $num_set;
say "IntStr(4,...) is 4: ", IntStr.new(4, "Four") == 4;
say "5 is in set: ", 5 ∈ $num_set;
```

A straight `4` is not in the set, but the [IntStr](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IntStr) version is:

```perl6
set: set(IntStr.new(4, "4"),IntStr.new(1, "1"),IntStr.new(2, "2"),IntStr.new(3, "3"))
4 is in set: False
IntStr 4 is in set: True
IntStr(4,...) is 4: True
5 is in set: False
```

I think most people aren't going to expect this, but the `∈` docs doesn't say anything about how this might work. I don't have this problem if I don't use the quote words (i.e. `set( 1, 2, 3, 4)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug, but not in the set stuff. The other answers were very helpful in sorting out what was important and what wasn't.

I used the [angle-brackets form of the quote words](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Word_quoting:_qw). The quote words form is supposed to be equivalent to the quoting version (that is, True under `eqv`). Here's the doc example:

```
<a b c> eqv ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

But, when I try this with a word that is all digits, this is broken:

```
 $ perl6
 > < a b 137 > eqv ( 'a', 'b', '137' )
 False
```

But, the other forms work:

```
> qw/ a b 137 / eqv ( 'a', 'b', '137' )
True
> Q:w/ a b 137 / eqv ( 'a', 'b', '137' )
True
```

The angle-bracket word quoting uses [IntStr](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IntStr):

```
> my @n = < a b 137 >
[a b 137]
> @n.perl
["a", "b", IntStr.new(137, "137")]
```

Without the word quoting, the digits word comes out as [Str]:

```
> ( 'a', 'b', '137' ).perl
("a", "b", "137")
> ( 'a', 'b', '137' )[*-1].perl
"137"
> ( 'a', 'b', '137' )[*-1].WHAT
(Str)
> my @n = ( 'a', 'b', '137' );
[a b 137]
> @n[*-1].WHAT
(Str)
```

You typically see these sorts of errors when there are two code paths to get to a final result instead of shared code that converges to one path very early. That's what I would look for if I wanted to track this down (but, I need to work on the book!)

This does highlight, though, that you have to be very careful about sets. Even if this bug was fixed, there are other, non-buggy ways that `eqv` can fail. I would have still failed because 4 as [Int](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Int) is not "4" as [Str](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str). I think this level of attention to data types in unperly in it's DWIMery. It's certainly something I'd have to explain very carefully in a classroom and still watch everyone mess up on it.

For what it's worth, I think the results of `gist` tend to be misleading in their oversimplification, and sometimes the results of `perl` aren't rich enough (e.g. hiding `Str` which forces me to `.WHAT`). The more I use those, the less useful I find them.

But, knowing that I messed up before I even started would have saved me from that code spelunking that ended up meaning nothing!

Comment: Could you clarify what you consider the bug to be? As far as I can tell, this is all by design: (a) `<...>` goes through [`&val`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/val), which returns allomorphs if possible (b) set membership is defined in terms of identity, which distinguishes between allomorphs and their corresponding value types; so I would not classify it as a bug, but 'broken' by design; or phrased another way, it's just the [WAT](http://design.perl6.org/S99.html#WAT) that comes with this particular [DWIM](http://design.perl6.org/S99.html#DWIM)

Comment: This was intentionally added, and is [part](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/6198907ce48e6c9d22e2a6cd691689c76462fbd6/S02-literals/listquote.t#L83-L93) of the [testsuite](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/6198907ce48e6c9d22e2a6cd691689c76462fbd6/S02-literals/allomorphic.t#L118-L173). ( I can't seem to find anywhere that tests for `<…>` being equivalent to `q:w:v<…>` and `<<…>>`/`«…»` being equivalent to `qq:ww:v<<…>>` )

Comment: The docs say the two lists should be eqv, and they are not. If they are not meant to be equivalent, the docs need to change. Nothing in https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Word_quoting:_qw mentions any of this stuff.

Comment: The documentation seems to be just wrong here, `<...>` does not correspond to `qw(...)`, but `qw:v(...)`. Cf [S02](https://design.perl6.org/S02.html#The_%3Aval_modifier) for the description of the adverb and [this test](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/e7adb53/S02-literals/allomorphic.t#L162..L167) that Brad was <del>looking for</del> *already linked to*

Comment: or perhaps not outright wrong, but rather 'just' misleading: `<...>` is indeed *a* `:w` form, and the given example code does compare equal according to `eqv`

Comment: Zoffix fixed the docs in https://github.com/perl6/doc/commit/fa0b8f643356a3db1e5e59fda4f153f48f90ee90

Comment: @raiph I think you should undelete your answer. It's good stuff. I think Perl 6 is in that tough step where it works and makes sense for the people creating it, but now it's time for the people who just want to use it. That's a different audience that will give up much sooner that I do. Zoffix's change to the docs goes a long way toward that.

Comment: @raiph that makes sense :)

Answer (score 7):

You took a wrong turn in the middle. The important part is what `nqp::existskey` is called with: the `k.WHICH`. This method is there for value types, i.e. immutable types where the value - rather than identity - defines if two things are supposed to be the same thing (even if created twice). It returns a string representation of an object's value that is equal for two things that are supposed to be equal. For `<1>.WHICH` you get `IntStr|1` and for `1.WHICH` you get just `Int|1`.

Comment: Ah, okay. I can see a lot of pain for regular people trying to debug these things.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Set) documentation, sets compare object identity, same as the [`===`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_%3D%3D%3D) operator:

> Within a Set, every element is guaranteed to be unique (in the sense that no two elements would compare positively with the === operator)

The identity of an object is defined by the [.WHICH](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Mu#method_WHICH) method, as timotimo elaborates in his answer.

Comment: That's not really clear from that statement. That's talking about which elements are in the set. Beyond that, even if you choose to compare with ===, you have to know how other things are stored. This is the sort of info that should show up next to the Set operators.

Comment: Indeed, I think I've found a bug. The qw docs says this should be true: `< a b 137 > eqv ( 'a', 'b', '137' )`, but in the same version of Rakudo Star I get false. It's different object types on each side.

Comment: Despite all this, your answer was the A-ha! moment that led me to look at the right thing. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 2):

## Write your list of numbers using commas

As you mention in your answer, your code works if you write your numbers as a simple comma separated list rather than using the `<...>` construct.

Here's why:

```
4 ∈ set 1, 2, 3, 4 # True
```

A bare numeric literal in code like the `4` to the left of `∈` constructs a single value with a numeric type. (In this case the type is Int, an integer.) If a `set` constructor receives a list of similar literals on the right then everything works out fine.

## `<1 2 3 4>` produces a list of ["dual values"](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#Allomorph)

The various `<...>` ["quote words"](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting#Word_quoting:_qw) constructs turn the list of whitespace separated literal elements within the angle brackets into an output list of values.

The foundational variant (`qw<...>`) outputs nothing but strings. Using it for your use case doesn't work:

```
4 ∈ set qw<1 2 3 4> # False
```

The `4` on the left constructs a single numeric value, type `Int`. In the meantime the `set` constructor receives a list of strings, type `Str`: `('1','2','3','4')`. The `∈` operator doesn't find an `Int` in the set because all the values are `Str`s so returns `False`.

Moving along, the huffmanized `<...>` variant outputs `Str`s unless an element is recognized as a number. If an element is recognized as a number then the output value is a "dual value". For example a `1` becomes an [IntStr](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IntStr).

According to the doc "an IntStr can be used interchangeably where one might use a Str or an Int". But can it?

Your scenario is a case in point. While `1 ∈ set 1,2,3` and `<1> ∈ set <1 2 3>` both work, `1 ∈ set <1 2 3>` and `<1> ∈ set 1, 2, 3` both return `False`.

**So it seems the `∈` operator isn't living up to the quoted doc's claim of dual value interchangeability**.

This may already be recognized as a bug in the `∈` set operation and/or other operations. Even if not, this sharp "dual value" edge of the `<...>` list constructor may eventually be viewed as sufficiently painful that Perl 6 needs to change.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other answers and point out a consistancy here between sets and [object hashes](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash#Object_hashes_and_type_constraints).

An object hash is declared as `my %object-hash{Any}`. This effectively hashes on objects `.WHICH` method, which is similar to how sets distinguish individual members.

Substituting the set with an object hash:

```
my %obj-hash{Any};

%obj-hash< 1 2 3 4 > = Any;
say "hash: ", %obj-hash.keys.perl;
say "4 is in hash: ", %obj-hash{4}:exists;
say "IntStr 4 is in hash: ", %obj-hash{ IntStr.new(4, "Four") }:exists;
say "IntStr(4,...) is 4: ", IntStr.new(4, "Four") == 4;
say "5 is in hash: ", %obj-hash{5}:exists;
```

gives similar results to your original example:

```
hash: (IntStr.new(4, "4"), IntStr.new(1, "1"), IntStr.new(2, "2"), IntStr.new(3, "3")).Seq
4 is in hash: False
IntStr 4 is in hash: True
IntStr(4,...) is 4: True
5 is in hash: False
```

Comment: I agree its not great, as it is.